# Pooling over channels in pytorch

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch, max-pooling

In tensorflow, I can pool over the depth dimension which would reduce the channels and leave the spatial dimensions unchanged. I'm trying to do the same in pytorch but the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/pooling.html) seems to say pooling can only be done over the height and width dimensions. Is there a way I can pool over channels in pytorch?
I've a tensor of shape `[1,512,50,50]` I'm trying to use pooling to bring the number of channels down to 3. 
I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562612/pytorch-maxpooling-over-channels-dimension) but did not find the answer helpful.

Comment: can you describe, mathematically, how you plan to reduce 512 numbers to just 3 (per channel)? dividing 512 to 3 groups and then taking the max over each group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to reduce the number of channels is using a 1x1 kernel:

```
import torch                                                                                                                                                                                               

x = torch.rand(1, 512, 50, 50)                                                                                                                                                                                  
conv = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 3, 1)                                                                                                                                                                             
y = conv(x)                                                                                                                                                                                                   

print(y.size())                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# torch.Size([1, 3, 50, 50])
```

If you really need to perform pooling along the channels dimension due to some reason, you may want to permute the dimensions so that the channels dimension is swapped with some other dimension (e.g. width).
This idea was referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562612/pytorch-maxpooling-over-channels-dimension).