# Pytorch - Apply pooling on specific dimension

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a 3 dimension vector. I would like to perform a 1d max pool on the second dimension.

According to the documentation of pytorch the pooling is always performed on the last dimension.

> https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#maxpool1d

For example:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(5, 64, 32)
>>> pool = nn.MaxPool1d(2, 2)
>>> pool(x).shape
torch.Size([5, 64, 16])
```

My desired output:

```
torch.Size([5, 32, 32])
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytorch maxpooling over channels dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562612/pytorch-maxpooling-over-channels-dimension)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply permute the dimensions:

```
x = torch.rand(5, 128, 32)
pool = nn.MaxPool1d(2, 2)
pool(x.permute(0,2,1)).permute(0,2,1)  # shape (5, 128, 32) -> (5, 64, 32)
```